# This 404 seems unavoidable - what am I doing wrong? [Ninject 2.0 with ASP.NET MVC 2 on .NET 4]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, ninject-2, ninject.web

I downloaded the fairly new [Ninject 2.0](http://github.com/enkari/ninject/zipball/master) and [Ninject.Web.Mvc](http://github.com/enkari/ninject.web.mvc) (targeting mvc2) sources today, and successfully built them against .NET 4 (release configuration). When trying to run an application using Ninject 2.0, i keep getting 404 errors and I can't figure out why.

This is my global.asax.cs (slightly shortified, for brevity):

```
using ...
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Mvc;
using Ninject.Modules;

namespace Booking.Web
{
    public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
    {        
        protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            Booking.Models.AutoMapperBootstrapper.Initialize();
            RegisterAllControllersIn(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            base.OnApplicationStarted();
        }

        protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            ...
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Entry", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );    
        }

        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            INinjectModule[] mods = new INinjectModule[] {...};
            return new StandardKernel(mods);
        }
    }
}
```

The `EntryController` exists, and has an `Index` method that simply does a `return View()`. I have debugged, and verified that the call to `RegisterAllControllersIn()` is executed. I have also tried to use [Phil Haacks Routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) but I still get a 404.

**What do I do to find the cause of this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your routes being registered?  Is that being called from the base class?

Also make sure that you are registering your controllers *properly*.  I'm not sure how Ninject's controller factory expects it, but it might require a specific name or something.

Comment: In Ninject 1.5, this was done automatically by the `NinjectHttpApplication` that I inherit. I took a look at the assembly in Reflector, and found no call to `RegisterRoutes()` in this version, but I'm not sure I can do one myself. Where do I get the `RouteTable` I need as argument?

Comment: Brilliant! I examined the `Application_Start()` method in `NinjectHttpApplication` even closer, and noticed that there was a binding for `RouteCollection` there. Adding a simple `RegisterRoutes(Kernel.Get<RouteCollection>());` to my init method solved the problem. Thanks!